# Paste data in/to/into the Excel-based calculator

Tags: prepositions, british-english

I am writing an instruction for an Excel-based calculator. Which preposition should I use?

> Paste data in/to/into the calculator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

paste data **into** the calculator.

> we use **into** to talk about the movement of something, usually, with
> a verb that expresses movement (e.g. go, come).
>
> it shows where something is or was going.

source - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-into?q=In%2C%20into)

Comment: You’re probably right, but since OP has not provided a complete sentence it could also be something like “Paste data in the calculator is stored in one of ten numbered memory locations M1-M10”

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Hopefully, they will clarify.